# Does a call to BPXBATCH from JCL use the priority of the batch job or is priority in OMVS independent?

Tags: unix, mainframe, zos, jcl

I am calling a shell script that does some processing from JCL using BPXBATCH like this:

```
//STEP2   EXEC PGM=BPXBATCH,                                              
//             PARM='SH PATHTOSCRIPT.SH MYARGUMENT'
```

The JCL has the service class with the highest priority. However, the shell script enters in a queue waiting for resources. Sometimes it runs quickly, and other times waits a lot of time for resources. The priority of the JCL seems to be independent of the shell script. I read maybe using the "nice" command in Unix would increase the priority of the shell script.

I want to be sure first, that the priority of a JCL from z/OS doesn't affect the priority of Unix process that was called from that JCL through BPXBATCH. I cannot find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Short Answer

To answer your question first: BPXBATCH runs in one address space, and the shell runs in a second address space. Commands issues by the shell may run in the same address space as the shell, or may run in more additional address spaces.

The BPXBATCH address space has got a service class, and the shell address space(s) has got a service class, probably a different one. Each service class has its own performance goal, and this tells the system how to manage that work.

### Detailed Answer

The z/OS workload manager (WLM) is responsible to assign work to a service classes when it is presented the new work. Service classes specify *performance goals*, and *importance level*s, not priorities. WLM manages all work in the system according to is *performance goal* based on the *importance* of the goal.

There are a couple (workload management) subsystems, that may start new work. Examples of such subsystems are

- JES, which manage batch work, i.e. batch jobs.
- TSO, which manages interactive TSO user work (TSO login).
- OMVS, which manages *forked*, and *non-locally spawned* z/OS UNIX work.
- STC, which manages started job workload.

This list is not complete; I listed only the subsystems that I need to answer the question.

When JES2/3 receives a job that shall run on the system, it presents some job attributes to WLM, and WLM assigns the job to a *service class*. It does so using WLM classification rules for subsystem type JES, and the attributes given.

Everything that runs in this job, i.e. in the job's address space will be managed towards the *performance goal* of the sercive class assigned. This includes z/OS UNIX work **that is run in this very address space**, i.e. work that is not started via UNIX fork(), or non-local spawn().

When a z/OS UNIX process starts an new process via fork(), or via non-local spawn(), this new work is handled by the WLM subsystem OMVS. The OMVS subsystem presents some attributes of the new process to WLM, and WLM assigns the process to a *service class*. It does so using WLM classification rules for subsystem type OMVS, and the attributes given. This kind of work is always runs in a separate, new address space.

BPXBATCH starts the (first) UNIX command it is told via `PARM=`, or `//STDPARM`, as a new process using either fork(), or spawn(). The spawn() may be a local spawn(), or a non-local spawn(). Which one is done depends on many factors, too complex to explain here.

The important point here is, when running `BPXBATCH` with `PARM='SH ...'`, the shell proces will always run in a separate, new address space and will be classified via WLM subsystem *OMVS*.

The result is BPXBATCH is running in one address space with its service class, and the shell is run in a second address space with its service class. The service classes may be the same, but usually they are different WLM defintions with different performance goals.

As a starter, have a look at [z/OS MVS Planning: Workload Management](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=mvs-zos-planning-workload-management)

### nice() on z/OS UNIX

nice() has no effect on z/OS UNIX, unless the system has been setup to support it. There is parameter `PRIORITYGOAL(...)` in BPXPRMxx parmlib member to setup a list of up to 40 *WLM service classes* that will be used in conjunction with nice(). I have never heard of anyone having set this parameter.

See [z/OS MVS Initialization & Tuning Reference](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=mvs-zos-initialization-tuning-reference) for details about BPXPRMxx member

Comment: One thing to add is that maybe he delay is caused by WLM JES2 Initiator Management (or even JES2's own initiator management). This could appear somewhat random - but isn't.

Comment: @Martin Packer You're generally right. But in this case the Q was about a script that was started via BPXBATCH, so there is no initiator delay.